# Responsive Columns Collapsing Too Soon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I want 3 columns to remain responsive throughout different sized (lg -> xs). I am trying to use the grid system with col-xx-4 for each size, but as soon as I get to <992px the column start collapsing on each other.

example can be see [here](http://dev.vs-works.com/dashboard-innov.html)

I want the red, green, and blue columns within the gray box to be always equal 3 columns. Maybe in xs they can collapse, but at least until 768px viewport they should be 3 columns next to each other.

I used col-xs-4 that should keep things horizontal at all times.

excerpt of some of my code:

```
                <div class="dash-bg">
                  <div class="" style="background: #d5d5d5; height: 500px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background: red; height: 30px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background: blue; height: 30px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background: green; height: 30px;">
                    </div>                        
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should add class "Row" to Header..

Code snippet here :

```
<div class="header row">
    <div class="logo pull-left" style="background:black;">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 6.2%;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="#">COMPANY<span class="arrow-down glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--
    <div class="navbar-header dropdown">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">              
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>          
            </button>
        <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html"></a>
    </div>
    -->
</div>
```

Defining DOM element **row** will make sure that the maximum height of any child DOM element will be the maximum height of the parent DOM.

Comment: -Rahul- That did it! I don't understand why it did. I don't see why the height was an issue when the width was causing me all the problems. Thank you SO much for your help.

Comment: Glad it solved the problem.. Make sure you always define row when you want that region to be distinct from other (e.g. Headers, Footers, Containers)... Region might overlap with other region of float property is given on element in first region (pull-right in your case)..

Please mark it as an Answer or upvote so that it will be helpful for others :-) Regards, Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) OR make your `dash-bg {min-width:993px;}`

Answer (score -1):

I have something similar and i use

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Something</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Something</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Something</div>
</div>
```

You can check an example [here](http://ragecatan.herobo.com/arranca/index.html)